# How to check for integers and special charectors in a string?

Tags: php

Iam making a signup page.
And I want to show an error whenever a user puts a numeric/special charector in Name field!

So is there any function that does the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can use regex. Example:

```
$str = 'test';
if(!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/', $str)){
    //echo 'invalid';
}
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/aG2aE6/2)

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex '/^[a-z][a-z ]*$/i'. It matches letters and spaces only.

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-z][a-z ]*$/i', $firstname)) {
    // firstname is invalid
}
```